# Extjs 5 Progress bar during initComponent

Tags: extjs, progress-bar

I have a tab panel, and I perform a server request in it's initComponent method to add tabs according to the result. This process can take a long time, and I would like to display a progress bar during the begining of initComponent, till the end (before the callParent call method for example).

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [LoadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask) on any pretty much any component, here is an example, there is also a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gvv):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'characters'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function() {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        });

        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(grid, {msg:"Please wait..."});
        myMask.show();

        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            myMask.hide();
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

I've added a setTimeout to replicate a long loading request, you do not need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to rely on "callParent" method. You have two options:

1. Make your server request synchronously. (by setting `async:false` for your `ext.ajax` call or for the related `operation`) It causes your code to be waited till the response comes.it blocks UI interaction but makes you sure having response immediately in line after server call
2. Another way is calling `this.setLoading(true)` before calling ajax call and setting `this.setLoading(false)` in your `ajax/operation callback method`. Note that `this` should refer to your main component. So it is bettor to save it in a variable at `initComponent` first line. For example by a line like `var me= this;`. After that refer to `current main component by`me`instead of`this`

Answer (score 0):

```
var progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar');

progressBar.wait({
    interval: 1000,
    duration: 10000,
    increment: 10,
    text: 'Adding tabs...',
    scope: this,
    fn: function() {
        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel');
        me.add(tabPanel);

        tabPanel.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Main tab'
        });
        tabPanel.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Chunk'
        });
        tabPanel.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'My girl'
        });

        progressBar.hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h08)